# Only output same value once from object array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, object, compare

Using jQuery, I want to only output the same values once from an object array. I figure I can create a temporary array and compare it as I iterate through the object but not quite sure how to do it.

The object looks like this,

```
[{"type":"Sample1","manufacturer":"Sample2","model":"Sample3"},{"type":"Sample1","manufacturer":"Sample4","model":"Sample5"}]
```

Say that I only want to output type Sample1 once,

```
var sampleObject,
    storage = [];

$.each( sampleObject, function( key, item ) {
    if (!$.inArray(storage.item == item)) {
        console.log(item);
        storage.push(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: What value are you giving to `storage`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include a part, see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised I could just do it like this instead and avoid the hassle of comparing arrays,

```
    var type,
        brand,
        model;

    $.each( data, function ( key, item ) {
        if ( item['type'] != type ) {
            // Output type
        }
        if ( item['manufacturer'] != brand ) {
            // Output brand
        }
        if ( item['model'] != model ) {
            // Output model
        }

        type = item['type'];
        brand = item['manufacturer'];
        model = item['model'];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using inArray wrong. From the jQuery docs:

```
jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )
```

It returns the position(index) where the value was found in the array.

```
if (!$.inArray(storage.item == item))
```

doesn't make sense. It should be:

```
if ($.inArray(item, storage.item)==-1)
```

But then too, the comparison is wrong. You should be iterating over each value in item and putting each value in the storage array.

Check if this is what you want:

```
$.each( sampleObject, function( key, item ) {
  var found = false;
  $.each(item, function (prop, val) {
    if($.inArray(val, storage) == -1){
       storage.push(val);
    } else {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  if (!found)
    console.log(item)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I took another approach and realised it could be solved in a simpler way as I don't really need to compare the arrays, see updated post.